# How to access Two switches (elements) individually inside a tableview cell in UI Testing

Tags: ios, iphone, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xctestcase

I am in UI Testing one of my screen of my project. I have a tableview one of its cell is containing one and two switches.I am able to access the first cell's switch (element) easily by

```
         let tablesQuery = app.tables
         let switchPrivateStream     =   tablesQuery.switches["Make Private Stream"]
         switchPrivateStream.tap()
```

[image: just like this]

but i am not able to find out any way to access the next remaining those two  switches (elements) which are in side cell.

Please tell me what i am doing wrong here?

the debug description of this screen is as Follows ( might be helpful )

**`"Attributes: Application, 0x1c0380410, pid: 11294, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}, label: \'DummyProject\'\nElement subtree:\n →Application, 0x1c0380410, pid: 11294, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}, label: \'DummyProject\'\n    Window, 0x1c03800d0, Main Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}\n      Other, 0x1c0380270, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 2.5}}\n      Other, 0x1c03804e0, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}\n        NavigationBar, 0x1c0380680, traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 20.0}, {320.0, 44.0}}, identifier: \'Create a Stream\'\n          Button, 0x1c03805b0, traits: 8589934593, {{8.0, 20.0}, {27.0, 44.0}}, label: \'back icon\'\n          Other, 0x1c0380820, traits: 8590000128, {{86.5, 30.0}, {147.5, 24.0}}, label: \'Create a Stream\'\n        Other, 0x1c0380750, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}\n          Other, 0x1c03808f0, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}\n            Table, 0x1c0380a90, traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 64.0}, {320.0, 504.0}}\n              Cell, 0x1c0380b60, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 64.0}, {320.0, 153.0}}\n                Button, 0x1c0380c30, traits: 8589934593, {{276.0, 75.0}, {33.0, 33.0}}, label: \'camera icon cover images\'\n                TextField, 0x1c0380d00, traits: 146029150208, {{10.0, 164.0}, {300.0, 50.0}}, placeholderValue: \'Stream Name\'\n                Image, 0x1c0380dd0, traits: 8589934596, {{0.0, 64.0}, {320.0, 153.0}}, identifier: \'add-stream-cover-image-placeholder\'\n                Other, 0x1c0380ea0, traits: 8589934592, {{15.0, 216.5}, {305.0, 0.5}}\n              Cell, 0x1c419e850, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 217.0}, {320.0, 170.0}}\n                TextView, 0x1c43804e0, traits: 140746078552064, {{10.0, 261.0}, {300.0, 98.0}}\n                StaticText, 0x1c4380680, traits: 8589934656, {{10.0, 242.0}, {300.0, 17.0}}, label: \'Stream Caption\'\n                Other, 0x1c43805b0, traits: 8589934592, {{15.0, 386.5}, {305.0, 0.5}}\n              Cell, 0x1c4380750, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 387.0}, {320.0, 60.0}}\n                Switch, 0x1c4380820, traits: 9007207844675585, {{263.0, 401.5}, {49.0, 31.0}}, label: \'Make Private Stream\', value: 0\n                StaticText, 0x1c43808f0, traits: 8589934656, {{10.0, 408.5}, {138.0, 17.0}}, label: \'Make Private Stream\'\n                Other, 0x1c43809c0, traits: 8589934592, {{15.0, 446.5}, {305.0, 0.5}}\n              Cell, 0x1c4380a90, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 447.0}, {320.0, 80.0}}\n                Switch, 0x1c4380b60, traits: 9007207844675585, {{263.0, 449.0}, {49.0, 31.0}}, label: \'Add Collaborators, Any one can edit\', value: 0\n                Switch, 0x1c4380c30, traits: 9007207844675585, {{263.0, 494.0}, {49.0, 31.0}}, label: \'Add Collaborators, Any one can edit\', value: 0\n                StaticText, 0x1c4380d00, traits: 8589934656, {{10.0, 456.0}, {138.0, 17.0}}, label: \'Add Collaborators\'\n                StaticText, 0x1c4380dd0, traits: 8589934656, {{10.0, 501.0}, {138.0, 17.0}}, label: \'Any one can edit\'\n                Other, 0x1c4380ea0, traits: 8589934592, {{10.0, 487.0}, {300.0, 0.0}}\n                  Other, 0x1c4380f70, traits: 8589934592, {{10.0, 487.0}, {300.0, 0.0}}\n                    CollectionView, 0x1c4381040, traits: 35192962023424, {{24.0, 487.0}, {273.0, 0.0}}\n                      Image, 0x1c0380f70, traits: 8589934596, {{291.5, 448.0}, {2.5, 36.0}}\n                      Image, 0x1c0381040, traits: 8589934596, {{26.5, 481.5}, {265.0, 2.5}}\n                Other, 0x1c0381110, traits: 8589934592, {{15.0, 526.5}, {305.0, 0.5}}\n              Cell, 0x1c03811e0, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 527.0}, {320.0, 80.0}}\n                Switch, 0x1c03812b0, traits: 9007207844675585, {{104.5, 561.5}, {49.0, 31.0}}, label: \'Collaborators can, Add Content, Add People\', value: 0\n                Switch, 0x1c0381380, traits: 9007207844675585, {{263.0, 561.5}, {49.0, 31.0}}, label: \'Collaborators can, Add Content, Add People\', value: 0\n                StaticText, 0x1c0381450, traits: 8589934656, {{10.0, 536.0}, {84.0, 17.0}}, label: \'Collaborators can\'\n                StaticText, 0x1c0381520, traits: 8589934656, {{10.0, 568.5}, {88.0, 17.0}}, label: \'Add Content\'\n                StaticText, 0x1c03815f0, traits: 8589934656, {{167.0, 568.5}, {88.0, 17.0}}, label: \'Add People\'\n                Other, 0x1c03816c0, traits: 8589934592, {{15.0, 606.5}, {305.0, 0.5}}\n              Cell, 0x1c0381790, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 607.0}, {320.0, 80.0}}\n                Other, 0x1c0381860, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 64.0}, {305.0, 0.5}}\n                Button, 0x1c0381930, traits: 8589934593, {{0.0, 64.0}, {137.0, 45.0}}, label: \'done button\'\n    Window, 0x1c0381a00, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}\n      Other, 0x1c0381ad0, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}\n    Window, 0x1c0381ba0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}\n      StatusBar, 0x1c0381c70, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 20.0}}\n        Other, 0x1c0381d40, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 20.0}}\n        Other, 0x1c0381e10, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 20.0}}\n          Other, 0x1c0381ee0, traits: 8388608, {{6.0, 0.0}, {41.0, 20.0}}, label: \'No SIM\'\n          Other, 0x1c0381fb0, traits: 8388608, {{52.0, 0.0}, {15.0, 20.0}}, label: \'3 of 3 Wi-Fi bars\', value: SSID\n          Other, 0x1c0382080, traits: 8389120, {{138.0, 0.0}, {49.0, 20.0}}, label: \'7:49 PM\'\n          Other, 0x1c0382150, traits: 8388608, {{280.0, 0.0}, {35.0, 20.0}}, label: \'100% battery power, Charging\'\nPath to element:\n →Application, 0x1c0380410, pid: 11294, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}, label: \'DummyProject\'\nQuery chain:\n →Find: Target Application 0x1c02a1c80\n  Output: {\n    Application, 0x1c0380410, pid: 11294, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}, label: \'DummyProject\'\n  }\n"`**

Comment: Set different tag for both Switch 110 and 220 respectively, and then access it with cell.contentView.viewWithTag(110) for first Swift and cell.contentView.viewWithTag(220) for second switch.

Comment: Thannks for respond but i am ui testing that means these cell.contentView.viewWithTag(110) would not work. as the class which i am using is  a XCTestCase sub class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this what i have just need to do is just setting an `Accessibility Identifier` in `storyboard` for that particular view in my case a `UISwitch`.

[image: Adding Accessibility Identifier in storyboard]

Now by this i can able to find out my `Switch` `XCUIElement` as following :

```
     let tablesQuery   = app.tables
     let switch101     =   tablesQuery.switches["Switch101"]
     switch101.tap()
```